# Lombok Inherithance: how to set default value for field in superclass without redeclaring it?

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Lombok and I need a way to **automatically set the value for a superclass field** in the subclass, **without redeclaring it**.

> It is working fine on its own (`@SuperBuiler` and `@Builder.Default`) when using the builder, but it is giving troubles with Spring-Data MongoDB.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both protected test.jackson.polymorphism.domain.enumeration.EvaluationType test.jackson.polymorphism.domain.models.EvaluationModel.type and private test.jackson.polymorphism.domain.enumeration.EvaluationType test.jackson.polymorphism.domain.models.QuantitativeEvaluationModel.type map to the same field name type! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!

    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.assertUniqueness(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:368)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:354)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity$AssertFieldNameUniquenessHandler.doWithPersistentProperty(BasicMongoPersistentEntity.java:348)
```

These are my classes:

```
public enum EvaluationType{
    QUALITATIVE, QUANTITATIVE;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class EvaluationModel {
    protected EvaluationType type;
    protected Integer evaluation;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QualitativeEvaluationModel extends EvaluationModel {
    /**
     * How to set the default value for this field
     * without redeclaring it?
     */
    @Builder.Default
    private EvaluationType type = EvaluationType.QUALITATIVE;
}
```

---

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QuantitativeEvaluationModel extends EvaluationModel {
    /**
     * How to set the default value for this field
     * without redeclaring it?
     */
    @Builder.Default
    private EvaluationType type = EvaluationType.QUANTITATIVE;

    @Builder.Default
    private String currencyCode = Currency.getInstance("EUR").getCurrencyCode();

    private BigDecimal economicValue;
}
```

How do I make these subclass to have a default value (mayb final) for the `type` field, but without redeclaring the field?
This should work both with the contructor and with the builder.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it sounds a bit like that you don't want a settable field, but just a fixed value depending on the subclass instance. In that case, a manually implemented getter method without any field is the better choice.

However, if you really want the user to be able to set a value different from the default, this is your way:

```
@SuperBuilder
public class QualitativeEvaluationModel extends EvaluationModel {
    
    public static abstract class QualitativeEvaluationModelBuilder<C extends QualitativeEvaluationModel, B extends QualitativeEvaluationModelBuilder<C, B>> extends EvaluationModel.EvaluationModelBuilder<C, B>
    {
        public QualitativeEvaluationModelBuilder() {
            type(EvaluationType.QUALITATIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

It defines the builder class exactly like Lombok would create it (Lombok will add anything that you didn't write manually). As it's really filled with generics, I used `delombok` to get it right.
Next, you have to define a default value for your builder instance simply by calling the builder's setter method for `type` in the builder's constructor.

In this way, users that don't call the `type()` method on the builder instance will get the default value. If you want something else as `type`, just call the `type()` method on the builder instance.

Note that this only affects the builder. If you also want to instantiate via (no-args) constructor, you have to manually implement the constructor and set the default there.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the builder method on your own and do initialization there. The default builder method name is `builder()` and even that can be customized with `@SuperBuilder(builderMethodName = "myBuilderMethodName")`

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class HttpError {

  private final int status;
  private String type;
  private String title;
  private String detail;
  private String instance;

}

@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class BadRequestError extends HttpError {

  public static BadRequestError.BadRequestErrorBuilder<?, ?> builder(){
    return new BadRequestError.BadRequestErrorBuilderImpl()
        .title("Bad Request")
        .status(400);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to fix this problem (not specific to Lombok) is to use an initializer block (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) in the subclasses.

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public class QualitativeEvaluationModel extends EvaluationModel {
    {
        super.type = EvaluationType.QUALITATIVE;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you cannot use the builder to set another value any more. So the `type()` method basically becomes useless.

Comment: This also only works when the field in the super type is protected or public. If it is private, then @JanRieke's solution does work.